# Can you program a Discord bot to select which TTS voice actor to use?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots, text-to-speech

EDIT: Just in case anyone is searching for answers... I figured out how to switch between Window's voice actors with the Say.js API. I originally tried "Zira" or "Microsoft Zira" for the voice, but it didn't work. The program wants "Microsoft Zira Desktop" or "Microsoft David Desktop" for the names instead. Examples:

> say.speak("Hello! My name is Zira!", 'Microsoft Zira Desktop', 1)

> say.speak("Hello! My name is David!", 'Microsoft David Desktop', 1)

---

I have an okay understanding of web javascript, but I am new to discord javascript. I've been trying to create a Discord bot that let's me select which voice actor I want to use for Text-To-Speech. So far I am only able to make it talk with windows' default voice. I'm currently using Discord.js and NodeJS. I've tried using Say.js (voice select only supported for Mac OS), p5.Speech, Spoken, and other APIs. I usually run into errors like these:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

ReferenceError: window is not defined

Is there a way to make web js work inside discord js? Is there a TTS API out there that does work with their bots? I have seen people use Google Assistant API in their bots, but I  rather avoid using it since it's not free.

Comment: Those errors sound like you're trying to use a library which is meant for browsers, which are transpiled with Babel and bundled with something like Webpack to deal with the ES6 module `import` and `export` syntax. `ReferenceError: window is not a defined` is a clear error which tells you that the package is probably only designed to work with a browser (since `window` is available when you're running JS in a browser).

Comment: Just to be clear, unless Discord provides a text-to-speech API for bots, it's irrelevant here. You're looking for a library or an API that provides text-to-speech whose voice you can change, and the output of which you can transmit to Discord.

Comment: I've seen other programmers use Google Assistant as a working API for discord, however, it's not free. I'm just wondering if there is something else out there that can work. Was also wondering if anyone had any luck "translating" web browser js to discord js.

Comment: @Lori It's best to post an answer if you find the solution, not edit the original post. (It's always welcomed to answer your own question! There's even an option for it on the "Ask" page.)